# Azure QnA Maker [Download Knowledgebase] delete "changeStatus"?

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

Last year I built a chatbot with [QnA Maker Knowledgebase](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/knowledgebases_download), and there's a field called 'changeStatus'.
But recently it's disappeared, does anybody know what happened?

Comment: As of now, we no longer have the changeStatus field. For the latest supported fields, please refer to [QnaMaker API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/5ac266295b4ccd1554da75ff).

Comment: @ranusharao if there's no longer have the changeStatus field, does any other field instead of it ?

Answer (score 0):

We would like to know about QnA pairs that have been modified in the Test environment but have not yet publishes to the prod environment. Are there any alternatives?